# Responsive file manager on subdomain

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

I have integrated responsive file manager with codeigniter everything works well on local host

However on remote server dialog.php and the responsive file manager source are on subdomain and images location are on main domain

When including cross domain on url I can’t get the images plus no errors on console

How to fix that?

Comment: show us file structure and code as well

Comment: If you see a white page, check you error logs. Or enable display_errors. But we kinda need to see a little more stuff here. [(read mvcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Abdullah which one you need the field id html code or

Comment: The base url is seller.a0twa.com and Rfm is hosted in this subdomain folder but the images are hosted in a0twa.com

Comment: `<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="<?php echo filemanager_url().'dialog.php?type=1&relative_url=0&field_id=image'; ?>" href="javascript:;" > <img id="image_preview" src="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" style="width:100px; height:100px;" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
                      <input id="image" name="image" type="text" value="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="hidden" >`

Comment: this code i get normal url for images like `http://example.com/catalog/demo/sony_logo.jpg` it's the correct image folder path however thumbs are not displayed, and even image picker isn't working

Comment: @A0twa have you checked the developer console of your browser for the error returned when image fetching fails?